# CSS height property value not considered when using overflow element

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

I am using css in div to display three blocks in a single page. Horizontal scroll can be hidden and vertical scrolling is enabled. The below code is written for this purpose, but the height of 100px given for each div is not considered by the browser. Below is my code:
    
      
         Title1

```
  <body>
    <div>
      <div id="div1" style="float: left; width: 355px; height = 100px; border:thin solid black; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden; ">
        1111111111111111111 <br>
        1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 
        1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br>
        1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 
        1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br>
        1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 
        1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br>
      </div>

      <div id="div2" style="float: left; width: 605px; height = 100px; border:thin solid black; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden; ">
        1111111111111111111 <br>
        1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 
        1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br>
      </div>

      <div id="div3" style="float: left; width: 360px; height = 100px; border:thin solid black; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden; ">
        <div id="div4">
          1111111111111111111 <br>
          1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 
          1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br>
        </div>
      </div>

      <br style="clear: left;" />
    </div>

</html>
```

Please help me solve this height problem.

Thanks
Jagadesh S

Comment: jsfiddle entry - http://jsfiddle.net/heyjag/cs3zV/1/

Answer (score 1):

You're using `height = 100px;`. This is incorrect syntax. It should be `height: 100px;`.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Title1 </title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <div id="div1" style="float: left; width: 355px; height: 100px; border:thin solid black; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden; ">
        1111111111111111111 <br>
        1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 
        1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br>
        1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 
        1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br>
        1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 
        1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br>
      </div>

      <div id="div2" style="float: left; width: 605px; height: 100px; border:thin solid black; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden; ">
        1111111111111111111 <br>
        1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 
        1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br>
      </div>

      <div id="div3" style="float: left; width: 360px; height: 100px; border:thin solid black; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden; ">
        <div id="div4">
          1111111111111111111 <br>
          1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 
          1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br> 1 <br>
        </div>
      </div>

      <br style="clear: left;" />
    </div>

</html>
```